# Softphone Layout Case object will not appear in Search Results

Tags: cti, softphone

I have setup a Softphone Layout to display Contact and Case objects when a call come and phone number matches records.  However only related Contact records appear and no Case records in the search results.  I am uncertain why this is the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have added an additional Phone field of some kind the only standard searchable phone field is SuppliedPhone which doesn't always get automatically populated.